# PHP wrapper to check page and not display content on certain pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a login form in a section of the footer on my site, and it shows on every page at the moment. I'd like to surpress it on the login form however as that features a larger login box on the page.

What code would i need to wrap the footer login box around to check if they page is the login page and not show if it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
 if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != 'login.php') {
      ....your form...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function built to check if you're looking at a specific page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

The other answer about checing $_SESSION is good, but this will let you just use an ID, so you could theoretically change the link url or check aginst some other property.